# Python + Pandas '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'

Tags: python, pandas

> Issue 1 - solved by using pd.to_datetime(df.Date, format='%Y-%m-%d'). Thanks to Michael

I am trying to find the latest date of each user using their ID

```
df['Latest Date'] = df.groupby(['ID'])['Date'].transform.('max')
df.drop_duplicates(subset='ID', keep='last',inplace=True)
```

But I am getting `'>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'`

I have used the same approach in the past and it worked fine.

When I did dytypes, I see 'ID' column is int64 and Date column as object because I converted the date column to `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')`

---

> Issue 2 solved - See Michael's comment 'For the edit'

But the output does not look right

I am trying to find the latest date of each user using their ID and assign those dates to new columns using the category

Dataframe = df

Data looks like below,

```
 ID   CATEGORY NAME      DATE
 1        fruits      2017-08-07 00:00:00   
 2        veggies     2018-01-25 00:00:00   
 1        fruits      2015-08-07 00:00:00
 2        veggies     2022-01-01 00:00:00
```

My code is below

```
//Converting the date format 
    df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date, format='%Y-%m-%d')

//transforming to identify the latest date
    df['Latest Date'] = df.groupby(['ID'])['Date'].transform.('max')

//keeping the last and dropping the duplicates
    df.drop_duplicates(subset='ID', keep='last',inplace=True)

//inserting new columns
    df['Fruits'] = ' '
    df['Veggies'] = ' '

//applying the latest dates to the newly created columns
    df.loc[((df['CATEGORY NAME'] == 'fruits')), 'Fruits'] = df['Latest Date']
    df.loc[((df['CATEGORY NAME'] == 'veggies')), 'Veggies'] = df['Latest Date']
```

I want the output like below

```
ID   CATEGORY NAME      DATE          Latest Date      Fruits      Veggies
 1        fruits      2017-08-07       2017-08-07    2017-08-07

 2        veggies     2022-01-01       2022-01-01                 2022-01-01
```

But my output looks odd. I don't have an error message but the output is not right

```
ID   CATEGORY NAME      DATE          Latest Date      Fruits      Veggies
 1        fruits      2017-08-07                    
 
 2        veggies     2022-01-01       2021-01-01                 2021-01-01 00:00:00
```

If you notice above

1. It did not identify the latest correctly
2. When applying the date values to the new column, its 00:00:00 time format also shows up
3. It did not drop duplicates

Not sure what's wrong

Comment: please check the date type is in datetime format or not and also check the type of id whether it is the integer or not. If not please convert them into the suitable format and try the condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strftime` converts a date to string. Did you want to keep it as a datetime object but change the format? Try this instead:

```py
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date, format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

### For the Edit

I'm not sure why you want the "Date" and "Latest Date" columns to be the same, but here is the code that will give you your desired table output:

```py
# Recreate dataframe
ID = [1,2,1,2]
CATEGORY_NAME =   ["fruits", "veggies", "fruits", "veggies"]      
DATE = ["2017-08-07 00:00:00", "2018-01-25 00:00:00", "2015-08-07 00:00:00", "2022-01-01 00:00:00"]
df = pd.DataFrame({"ID":ID,"CATEGORY NAME":CATEGORY_NAME, "Date":DATE})

# Convert datetime format
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date, format='%Y-%m-%d')

# Get the max date value and assign the group to a new dataframe
dfNew = df.groupby(['ID'], as_index=False).max()

# The new dataframes Date and Latest Date column are the same
dfNew['Latest Date'] = dfNew['Date']

# Fix latest Date formatting 
dfNew["Latest Date"] = dfNew["Latest Date"].dt.date

# Add fruit and veggie columns
dfNew['Fruits'] = ' '
dfNew['Veggies'] = ' '

# Place in the desired values
dfNew.loc[((dfNew['CATEGORY NAME'] == 'fruits')), 'Fruits'] = dfNew['Latest Date']
dfNew.loc[((dfNew['CATEGORY NAME'] == 'veggies')), 'Veggies'] = dfNew['Latest Date']
dfNew
```

Output:

```
    ID  CATEGORY NAME   Date       Latest Date     Fruits         Veggies
0   1   fruits          2017-08-07  2017-08-07     2017-08-07   
1   2   veggies         2022-01-01  2022-01-01                    2022-01-01
```

Comment: You are right. This solved my problem. But I wonder how the other one worked! Thank you so much

Comment: although the error message is gone, the output does not look right. I have updated my post above.

Comment: Updated the answer to match your desired output

Comment: You are a superhero! Thank you, it worked. But there has been a small issue. When you did 'max' you did not mention, max of what? in my previous code, i mentioned the max of date for the same id. But without you mentioning that, it worked but the right category name is not showing. Only the correct date is updated.. My second question is, you asked why I created the second date column. My assumption was, that I need to create a second column to show the transformed max value without disturbing the original. See my updated post

Comment: I solved the second issue mentioned in my post. It was way more simple than I imagined. Just in one line

df.sort_values(by='DATE', ascending = False).drop_duplicates(subset='ID')